# Checkbox is not showing checked when setting value to true

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i am using iCheck in an angular application, i have a basic checkbox when checked shows an image. this works perfectly with ng-show, however when i set the value to true within my controller it doesn't return checked when page is loaded.

**Controller**

```
$scope.basicIntake = {};
$scope.basicIntake.insurance_cover = true;
```

**html**

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <label>
                        <input icheck type="checkbox"  ng-model="basicIntake.insurance_cover">
                            click to see image
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <img ng-src="http://i.imgur.com/vkW3Lhe.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" ng-show="basicIntake.insurance_cover">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: That code doesn't make much sense, but in any case to make a checkbox be checked you need to set the "checked" attribute to `true`, not the "value".

Comment: Just bind to `ng-checked="basicIntake.insurance_cover"`

Comment: @miguelLattuada it works if i set 'ng-checked="true"' however not when i set it to be 'ng-checked="basicIntake.insurance_cover"' i am still new to angularjs so possibly to do with scopes?

Comment: Did you removed ng-model? You have to keep it. Take a look at this example http://jsbin.com/lesiyaloti/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @MiguelLattuada yeah i have included both and its not showing on load. its the same as that example i even changed how the object is defined to match. could it be to do with iCheck ?

Comment: @miguellattuada i just added {{basicIntake.insurance_cover}} to the html to see what is loaded in and its blank until i click the checkbox. then true and false is displayed

Comment: Did you removed icheck directive? Maybe it's causing an undesired behavior.

Comment: Are you doing these changes on the initial load or _after_ page load? Sorry I don't know Angular, but work with `iCheck` a lot.

Comment: @miguellattuada yes i removed icheck and still doesn't display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your template is not bound to any controller with directive `ng-controller`.
Your properties are not created till you make any event. like : `click`.

See this attached [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lp9tzbg6/) and try to connect.
try to remove `ng-controller` from top `Div` to get your problem.

Further: there is no need to have `ng-checked`, when you already have `ng-model`

Comment: Thanks, you telling me to remove ng-controller allowed me to spot my mistake. i had a close </div> right after the the open <div>. Its friday and IDE's intellisense can be helpful sometimes, but sometime in this case not. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
<input icheck type="checkbox"  ng-model="basicIntake.insurance_cover">
```

to:

```
<input icheck type="checkbox" ng-checked="basicIntake.insurance_cover" ng-model="basicIntake.insurance_cover" ng-click="checkAll()">
```

And it will work.

(Miguel Lattuada also suggested it in a comment to your question)

Comment: i have tried that but still doesn't show checked, the basicIntake.insurance_cover does change to true, however when page is load this value is blank. i tested by adding {{basicIntake.insurance_cover}} to html as a test to see what displays.

Comment: I edited the answer, you sould also use: ng-click="checkAll()"

Comment: FYI, `<input type="checkbox">` are checked via the `checked` attribute (it's enough if it's present, no value needed, e.g. `checked="checked"`). The `value` attribute is used to tell the browser what to send to the server when the box is checked. When the box is not checked, that variable is not sent at all.